# How do I calculateAverage?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function in Javascript that is called calculateAverage which accepts arrays of numbers. The function should return the average in the array. If the array is empty, return 0.

I am new to coding and have only studied python.

```
int calculateAverage(int numbers_count, int* numbers) {
calculateAverage([50, 21, 80])
calculateAverage([30, 39, 58, 11])
calculateAverage([200])
calculateAverage([])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show your current code. And explain what you've tried yourself first. Before posting, you should [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052)

Comment: But in short: `const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;`, then run:  `average([1,3,5,8,13,21])`

Comment: Share what have you tried so far. Just to direct your way forward, sum all the values of the array then divide the sum by the length of the array, to calculate the average of an array...

Comment: Your function header looks more like C than JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: it was in C. Thank you for pointing that out. @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

this can be a solution:

```
 function calculateAverage(arr) {
  const sum = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
  return sum / arr.length
}

const arr = [5,10,1,5,20,50,30,25];

const average = calculateAverage(arr);
console.log(average)
```

Comment: If you added documentation to `reduce` in your answer, or some explanation, it would be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that like this...

```js
function calculateAverage(arr) {
  const rslt = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;
  return 0 === ~~rslt ? 0 : rslt;
}

console.log(calculateAverage([30, 39, 58, 11]));
```

Comment: One Liner Function:   `function calculateAverage(a){const b=a.reduce((c,d)=>c+d,0)/a.length;return 0===~~b?0:b}`

Comment: This will output 0 if the array is empty, otherwise it will output the average.

Comment: If you added documentation to `reduce` in your answer, or some explanation, it would be more useful.

Comment: The reduce() method executes a reducer function for array element. Here is the documentation link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: As I've commented before: To calculate the average of an array in JavaScript: Sum all the values of the array. Divide the sum by the length of the array.

Comment: _I_ know what it does. _You_ know what it does. But the _OP_ might not know which is why you should add relevant links to your answer, and notes, to explain what your code does. Otherwise it's just a code-dump, and not very useful.